# execute php file from php form action

Tags: php

How can I run php file from another php file with onclick button?

My first.php file:

```
echo "<form action='saveResult.php' method='post' name='Post'>";
echo "<input name='Save' type='submit' value='Save Result'> </p>";
```

I want to run 'saveResult.php' from my first.php without redirect to 'saveResult.php' page.

Thanks,

**Edit 1:**
I try:

```
echo "<form action='' method='POST' name='Post'>";
echo "<input name='Save' type='submit' value='Save Result'>";   
echo "</form>";
if(isset($_POST['Save'])){
require_once('saveResult.php'); // display error
include_once('saveResult.php'); // display error
include('saveResult.php'); // display error
}
```

The error is:
HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onclick replace php included file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618576/onclick-replace-php-included-file)

Comment: first, show your complete code, how will it work property if you dont even close the `<form>-tag`. And second, `action= ` always redirect, even if its pointed to itself. If you dont want it, use jacascript with `onclick`-function on your button and `ajax`-call.

Comment: @yangsunny How can I use js inside php file!

Answer (score 1):

First remove action from your form tag

```
echo "<form method='post' name='Post'>";
```

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST['Save']))
{ 
   include('secondpage.php');
}
```

Comment: if(isset($_POST['Save'])) always display an error. I write form action=''

Comment: HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

Comment: @Alaa have you removed the action?

Answer (score 0):

> Change method "post" to "POST"

Change your from action attribute to blank("") and then include that file in first.php with PHP functions like

```
if(isset($_POST['Save'])){
    include_once('saveResult.php');
}
```

OR

```
if(isset($_POST['Save'])){
    require_once('saveResult.php');
}
```

Comment: Your answer is partial true. OP has asked "with onclick button".

Comment: if(isset($_POST['Save'])) always display an error. I write form action=''

Comment: @Mihir Bhatt HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

Answer (score 0):

please add the following code to your code

```
echo "<form action='' method='post' name='Post'>";
echo "<input name='Save' type='submit' value='Save Result'> </p>";
if(isset($_POST['Save'])){
    ob_start();
    include('saveResult.php');
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo '>>>>' . $output . '<<<<';   // here is the output from saveResult.php
}else{
    echo "No POST";
}
```

Hope this will help you.. Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

Is your web server configured to handle PHP files for POST verbs?

**EDIT**

Try to configure this in IIS through going into Handler Mappings, and editing the PHP script map to handle the POST verb

**EDIT**

To add Handlers visit this link please. 
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/handlers/add

Importent, check in tab 'verbs' that you have entered '*' or 'GET,HEAD,POST'

Comment: You should give comments directly to the question instead of asking as an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Alaa Please check this link. Add a Module Handler Mapping |  [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731285%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: @Basti could you please give me the detailed step? what should I write in Module? and Excutable?